# How to build a image slider in desktop

Tags: flutter, image-slider, stacking-context

[image: Example]
Trying to build something like this, issue is dont know where to start with combinning the stack and listview builder

Tried using a list view builder , work if images are next to eacher other plain, but getting stuck with zoom image and stacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't reinvent the wheel!**

The type of image slider you're trying to create would be called a "carousel slider"

There are [plenty of packages](https://pub.dev/packages?q=carousel%20slider) to create this.

I've answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76862259/12349734) from where I will adapt this code example:

> ```
> import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> final List<String> imgList = [
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
>   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
> ];
>
> void main() => runApp(ImageSliderDemo());
>
> class ImageSliderDemo extends StatelessWidget {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>       home: Scaffold(
>         appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Image slider demo')),
>         body: Center(
>             child: CarouselSlider(
>           options: CarouselOptions(
>             enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
>             enlargeCenterPage: true,
>           ),
>           items: imgList
>               .map((item) => Container(
>                     child: Center(
>                         child: Image.network(item,
>                             fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
>                   ))
>               .toList(),
>         )),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to achieve your goal.